# how to create a pull request on bitbucket when local branch already exists

Tags: git, bitbucket, pull-request

I already made a feature branch on my local repository and committed my changes to it. Say it's called `feature_x`. This branch does not exist at the origin, which is bitbucket.org.

I want to make a pull request of my changes to the `develop` branch on bitbucket so my teammates can do a code review.

I do see the instructions on bitbucket for creating a pull request and I started to go through that dialog, but one of my obstacles is I need a branch on bitbucket to do the pull request from, but I only have a local feature branch.

Comment: `git push origin feature_x`, then create the pull request on Bitbucket web and select `develop` as the destination branch.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, `error: src refspec feature_x_toddmo does not match any.` I can't use the same name as what's in local because my boss uses that name for his stuff. Normally we just push to develop and there's no conflict.

Comment: Do `git fetch origin`, then do `git branch -a`.  Do you see a remote tracking branch called `origin/feature_xx_toddmo`?  If you _don't_, then this branch does not exist in your remote repository.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I know. But if I can push to origin feature_x, why won't it let me push to origin feature_x_toddmo?

Comment: Wait...is your local branch `feature_x` or `feature_x_toddmo`?  If you want to push local branch `A` to another branch, you can do this, but there is a different syntax.  Typically, you bring one branch into another via a merge though.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, it's `feature_x`. Why because I already created it locally and that's just the point that I'm at. Had I known in advance I would have called it `feature_x_toddmo` to make it easier to do the push. But this is where I'm at.

Comment: Edit your question and show the exact commands you are running here.  Most likely, the appropriate thing to do here would be to just open a pull request from `feature_x` to `feature_xx_toddmo` on Bitbucket web.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, the commands you requested are in the answer. I usually include a "what I've already tried" section in the question but in this case I really hadn't tried anything. The command you provided which gave the error wasn't part of what I had tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These commands did what I needed to do on my side in order for bitbucket to be able to do a pull request. I was on a branch called `feature_X`:

```
git branch -m feature_X_toddmo
git push --set-upstream origin feature_X_toddmo
```